# why Attribute count is 0 for this XML Tag

Tags: xml, dom, xml-parsing, sax, stax

I am using STAX Parser for parsing the XML documents .
I have this below tag

```
<bustxml><![CDATA[&lt;bustxml xmlns=\"http://www.bustprotocol.org/bustxml-5-0-SP2\"&gt;&lt;NewOrdMBag TmInForce=\"0\" OrdTyp=\"1\" Acct=\"1234\"&gt;&lt;Ord OrdQty=\"1\" </bustxml>
```

I need to read the attributes of the above tag , so i used

```
 case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                 for(int i = 0, n = reader.getAttributeCount(); i < n; ++i)
                  System.out.println("Attribute: " + reader.getAttributeName(i) 
                             + "" + reader.getAttributeValue(i));
```

**But unfortunately i am getting , Attrbute Count as 0 .**
Please tell me how can i read all the contents inside the bustxml tag

Comment: FYI in your sample you open a CDATA section without closing it

Comment: Hi Justin , for the security i didn't post the whole XML . so i guess that is not a issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bustxml element outside the CDATA has no attributes.

The bustxml inside the CDATA is not a tag. That's what CDATA means: "This is character data. Don't treat anything you find in here as markup." So the content might look like a tag, but it's not a tag, because of the CDATA, and therefore it has no attributes.

Unfortunately it's very common for people to take XML and wrap inside CDATA. They do this to make your life difficult. (Well I assume that's the reason, I can't think of any other.) When this happens your only remedy is to extract the text inside the CDATA and submit it to an XML (or HTML) parser to turn it into a tree, and then you can access the elements and attributes in the normal way.

In your case they've made it doubly difficult by not only wrapping it in CDATA, but escaping it as well. So they've effectively double-escaped it, so you're going to have to put it through the parser twice (in addition to the orginal parse) to make sense of it.

I would complain very loudly to the people who sent you this rubbish.

Answer (score 2):

The `bustxml` element has no attributes, if it did it would look like this:

```
<bustxml MyAttribute="MyValue">
<!-- Content -->
</bustxml>
```

If you want to read the content of the `bustxml` element then you should use `getElementText` instead.

**Update:** If you are talking about the `bustxml` element in the encoded xml fragment contained in the CDATA section then you need to extract the text of this CDATA fragment and then parse / extract attributes from it instead.

Comment: Thank you , where should i use this getElementText  or getText  ? Because reader.getAttributeCount(); is 0 now , (As per the attribute count)

Comment: @yyyi777 I believe that you should use `getElementText` however I'm not 100% sure (I'm normally a C# developer)

Comment: I tried to extract the contents of CData using , bustxml = reader.getName().toString() ; but still how can we get the Attribute count from this ??